# Give different ID to each element in for loop

Tags: php, css, loops

I have a far loop which check the number and output the result to number of that.

For exmaple, in below picture the "cut image" is displayed in multiples times. I have  tag in the far loop so it outputs the image according to number of times. And that number come from database.

**MY Question.** 
Obviously all the images in first row will have same ID. Currently user can only click the first image of the row. I would like to give each element different ID  if possible. Than I would like to use JQuery to add click event. So if I click on 4th image in first row, it alert message and if i click 5th image it shows different alert message.

How I can assign different ID to each element in far loop so  it does only make first Image clickable but instead all elements clickable.

[image]

My loop

```
 <table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <?php
        for($x=0; $x < $row['noof10s_vnr']; $x++){ 
            ?>

            <td><img alt="" class="yellow-process center-block " id ="cut-full-roll-<?php echo $row['id_vnr']; ?>" name="<?php echo $row['id_vnr']; ?>" src="../../css/icons/vinyl-rolls/cut.png"></td>
        <?php
        }
        ?>

      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

My jquery selector
If I can give each element different ID, than I can do something like this to add clicked event to clicked image.

```
jQuery( "#vinyl-roll-down-<?php echo $row['id_vnr']; ?>" ).click(function() {
```

But I need help assign different unique to each element in far loop.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Put the click handler on the class and then access `$(this)` to get the specifics of the image clicked

Comment: It seems like your loop is incorrect. Would be really helpful with some sample data. Like what 'noof10s_vnr' is, and what the row is. Your loop just outputs the same row over and over. You kind of already have an id, and that is $x. You increment it every time, so just use that?

Comment: That would be fine. But at the moment the first image of each row is clickable. All images in a single row have same ID, so only first is clickable. I would like to give different unique ID to each elements in a row, than i can add a click event

Answer (score 3):

I think your loop in PHP is okay like that.
The problem lies in your jquery, try getting the right id by using use attribute 
selector `attr("id")`.

```
jQuery( ".yellow-process" ).click(function() {
    var selected = jQuery(this).attr("id");
    alert(selected); // to show the selected image id
    // use the variable selected to do something with it.
}
```

After trying this jquery code you could advance it for your use.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

**In html:**

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <?php
        for($x=0; $x < $row['noof10s_vnr']; $x++){
        ?>
        <td><img id="image{{$x}}" alt="" class="yellow-process center-block " onclick="imageClick(<?php echo $row['id_vnr']; ?>)" name="<?php echo $row['id_vnr']; ?>" src="../../css/icons/vinyl-rolls/cut.png"></td>
        <?php
        }
        ?>

    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**in jquery**

```
function imageClick(id) {
    alert(id);
  var imageId = jQuery(this).attr("id");
   alert(imageId);
//    your code
}
```

I thigh it will help you.

Comment: Thank you Binhudatta Sahoo. I like this method. Is there any way to sort of differentiate each element. At the moment if I click any image in first row, it will show same ID. I would like to treat each image differently now.

Comment: Yes @Muhammad Ikram you can do this ,just try the edited answer once.

Answer (score -2):

```
$( ".yellow-process" ).bind("click",function() {
    var selected = $(this).attr("id");
    alert(selected); // to show the selected image id
    // use the variable selected to do something with it.
});
```

Your php code written in the right way and working as expected just for jquery above is the working code